# KivyMD - Cannot Update TextField's text when used in DialogBox

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I have used **KivyMD** to develop a Screen which displays the Parameter values (In a **DialogBox**) of specific Item (which I listed them as **OnelinelistItem**). I also want to make provision for the user to change the parameter values from the DialogBox. But apparently I cant update the parameter settings from the DialogBox. The DialogBox contains the **Textfield**. Can anyone help me to figure out the issue, by going through the code, and let me know, where I am doing it wrong?
**TIA**! :)

**testingsetpointpage.py**

'''

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'systemanddock')
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
Window.size = (1024, 600)
```

The Builder is shown here:

```
KV = """
#:kivy 1.11.0
#:import MDDropdownMenu kivymd.uix.menu.MDDropdownMenu
#:import MDRaisedButton kivymd.uix.button.MDRaisedButton
ScreenManager:
    MainScreen:
<MainScreen>:   
    name: 'mainscreen'
    NavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            Screen:                
                name: 'homemain'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation:"vertical"
                    halign:"center" 

                    #DOWN TAB          
                    MDBottomNavigation:                        
                        MDBottomNavigationItem:
                            name: 'setpoint'
                            text: 'Setpoints'
                            icon: 'network'
                              
                            BoxLayout:
                                orientation: "vertical"
                                
                                MDToolbar:
                                    title: 'Setpoints'
                                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.95}   
                                    right_action_items: [["wifi", lambda x: app.navigation_draw()]]
                                    left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
                                    elevation: 10
                                
                                BoxLayout:
                                    orientation:"vertical"
                                    padding: 5
                                    spacing: 5
                                    MDLabel:
                                        text: "     Functions: "
                                        halign:"left"
                                        theme_text_color: "Custom"
                                        text_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
                                        size_hint_y: 0.15
                                        canvas.before:
                                            Color:
                                                rgba: (211/255.0,211/255.0,211/255.0,1)
                                            Rectangle:
                                                size: self.size
                                                pos: self.pos
                                    SetpointContent:
                                    
#MAKE THE PARAMETER LIST                                            
<SetpointContent>: 
 
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding: 5
        spacing: 5

        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                OneLineListItem:
                    text: "51P: Phase Time Overcurrent"
                    on_press: root.show_51Pdata()
                
    
<Content51P>
    alarmpick51p: alp51p
    alarmdelay51p: ald51p
    trippick51p: trp51p
    invcurve51p: inp51p
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "200dp"
    GridLayout:
        rows: 4
        cols: 2
        spacing: 10
        
        MDLabel:
            text: "Alarm Pickup: "
            halign: "center"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            size_hint_y: 0.15
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            width:100
        MDTextFieldRect:
            id: alp51p
            text: root.text1
            multiline: False
        MDLabel:
            text: "Alarm Delay: "
            halign: "center"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            size_hint_y: 0.15
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            width:100
        MDTextFieldRect:
            id: ald51p
            text: str(app.Aldelay51P)
            multiline: False
        MDLabel:
            text: "Trip Pickup:  "
            halign: "center"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            size_hint_y: 0.15
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            width:100
        MDTextFieldRect:
            id: trp51p
            text: str(app.Trpick51P)
            multiline: False
        MDLabel:
            text: "Inverse Curve:  "
            halign: "center"
            theme_text_color: "Custom"
            text_color: 0, 0, 1, 1
            size_hint_y: 0.15
            size_hint_x: 0.4
            width:100
        MDTextFieldRect:
            id: inp51p
            text: str(app.InverseCurve)
            multiline: False
                            #####                                                                         
"""
```

and the Classes are defined here:

```
class Content51P(BoxLayout):
    app=MDApp.get_running_app()
    text1 = StringProperty("1")
    alarmpick51p = ObjectProperty()
    alarmdelay51p = ObjectProperty()
    trippick51p = ObjectProperty()
    invcurve51p = ObjectProperty()



class MainScreen(Screen):
    class SetpointContent(Screen):

        def show_51Pdata(self):
            self.dialog = MDDialog(title="51P Parameters:",
                                   type="custom",
                                   content_cls=Content51P(),
                                   buttons=[MDFlatButton(text='Close', on_release=self.close_dialog),
                                            MDFlatButton(text='Update', on_release=self.update51P)]
                                   )
            self.dialog.auto_dismiss = False
            self.dialog.open()

        def update51P(self, obj):
            duc = Content51P()
            app = MDApp.get_running_app()
            duc.text1 = duc.ids.alp51p.text
            print(duc.text1)
            app.Alpick51P = float(duc.text1)
            print(app.Alpick51P)

        def close_dialog(self, obj):
            self.dialog.auto_dismiss = True
            self.dialog.dismiss()


class MainApp(MDApp):
    Alpick51P = ObjectProperty("5")
    Aldelay51P = ObjectProperty("5")
    Trpick51P = ObjectProperty("5")
    InverseCurve = ObjectProperty("Very Inverse")

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Blue"
        screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return screen

    def navigation_draw(self):
        print("Navigation")

    def on_start(self):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

'''
[The outlook looks something like this. I want to update the four parameters as the user clicks on the Update button and be able to view the value, the next time I open the DialogBx.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aoe6a.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the kv rule, under `<Content51P>` for `MDTextFieldRect` textinputs add:

```
on_text: app.Alpick51P = self.text
on_text: app.Aldelay51P = self.text
on_text: app.Trpick51P = self.text
on_text: app.InverseCurve = self.text
```

The `on_text` method should go to respective `MDTextFieldRect`.

Update the `update51P()` function should be like below now:

```
        def update51P(self, obj):
            app = MDApp.get_running_app()
            print(app.Alpick51P)
            print(app.Aldelay51P)
            print(app.Trpick51P)
            print(app.InverseCurve)
```

This would now print the updated inputs from textinput fields.